# Spark Sql to print empty string with particular length

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, airflow

I am trying to convert below to spark sql to run this in airflow

```
case when length(trim(cast(nvl(table.aa_bb_cnt ,'') as varchar(8))))=0 then '0' else cast(table.aa_bb_cnt as varchar(8 )) end as aa_bb_cnt
```

thanks

here in spark sql , I can not use varchar with cast. Only string data type is support. I should be to use substr to cut the string form first to 8th character, but in case if value is null, how do i print 8 empty string?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

> I should be to use substr to cut the string form first to 8th character, but in case if value is null, how do i print 8 empty string

What about using both `coalesce` and `repeat` for such purpose ?
`Coalesce` is the same as `nvl` in spark-sql.

```sql
with data as (
    select '12345678' as str 
    union select null),
result as (
    select coalesce(substring(str, 1, 8), repeat(' ', 8)) as res 
    from data)
select res, length(res) as char_length 
from result
```

This results as (both having length 8):

```
+--------+-----------+
|     res|char_length|
+--------+-----------+
|12345678|          8|
|        |          8|
+--------+-----------+
```